# Why is it “millions d'années” and not “millions d'ans”?

Tags: vocabulaire, nombres, indications-de-temps

We are given the impression that “soirée”, “matinée” and “année” are for specific or even special occasions.

Why therefore, when talking about 1 000 000 years, does French prefer this form? Surely there are so many years here that we care little about them individually.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that *soirée/matinée/année* have to be about specific or special occasions but they have some properties setting them aside from *soir/matin/an*:

1. they do not have to be contiguous:

   - +*J'ai passé deux années en Malaisie, 1991 et 2005*
   - ?*J'ai passé deux ans en Malaisie, 1991 et 2005*
2. they are compatible with internal quantification:

   - +*toute la soirée/matinée/année* vs ?*tout le soir/matin/an*
   - +*la soirée/matinée/année entière* vs ?*le soir/matin/an entier*
   - +*pendant la soirée/matinée/année* vs ?*pendant le soir/matin/an*

As for *un million d'années*, the problem might lie somewhere else altogether. The two following expressions would be ok:

- *un million trois cent mille années* & *un million trois cent mille ans*

But French has this strange thing with *1 000 000* which must be constructed as an NP taking the counted noun as an indefinite complement the same way *un grand nombre* does:

- *un grand nombre **de** chats*
- *un million **de** chats*

In general, *ans* seems to avoid indefinite plural contexts:

- ?*des ans*, ?*quelques ans* vs +*des années*, *quelques années*

And so it happens that we get :

- ***un million d'années***

Answer (score 3):

The longer form `année` does not imply a special occasion. It is used to stress the period's duration. Roughly speaking, `an` is the point in time (`J'ai cinquante ans`), and `année` is the period (`Il faut compter une année pour voyager à Mars`). The same goes for `nuit`/`nuitée`, `matin`/`matinée`, `soir`/`soirée`, `jour`/`journée`.

Note: a similar distinction is found in e.g. `cuiller (or cuillère)` vs `cuillerée`, where the former simply denotes a spoon, and the latter the volume it can contain (spoonful, as in recipes). Other examples include `bouche`/`bouchée` and `bol`/`bolée`. It is, generally speaking, a way of expressing an entity's extension in space or time.

Comment: What about "how long did the journey last?" : le voyage a duré une nuit/ deux jours.On pourrait dire "il a duré une matinée" , mais personne ne dirait "il a duré une nuitée". Journée pourrait être utilisé, mais suivi ou précédé de quelque chose qui le modifie, sinon ça sonnerait bizarre. Ex. "le voyage a duré deux journées entières"  mais "le voyage a duré deux jours." (duration). Je pense que l'utilisation de l'un ou l'autre est devenu surtout idiomatique, même s'il y avait une règle au départ.

Comment: @P.Obertelli  "Le voyage a duré deux journées entières" : les deux journées ont été entièrement occupée par le voyage ;  "le voyage a duré deux jours." : le voyage s'est effectué sur deux jours : le 1er et 2 mars par exemple, il a pu commencer à 16h et se terminer à 11h le lendemain

Comment: ça illustre mon point, dire que dans la phrase "le voyage a DURÉ deux jours " les deux jours n'expriment pas une durée...c'est vraiment tiré par les cheveux. L'usage a pris le pas sur les règles.

Comment: J'oubliais: "trois mille ans" , "trois millions d'années" "nous sommes en l'an 2000", "nous sommes l'année 1984" "nous sommes en l'an 1984"...c'est devenu avant tout une question d'usage. Ce qui n'empêche pas qu'au départ les règles énoncées s'appliquaient.

Comment: Wow I had no idea *nuitée* was a word...never heard that one. Also, frankly, I still find this confusing, because truthfully *j'ai cinquante ans* is referring to a duration, too, in a manner of speaking. 5 years of life.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Not quite. Saying `J'ai cinquante ans` (which, by the way, is fifty years, not five) is a statement about the current situation. `J'ai vécu cinquante années` stresses how long it took you to get there. Age and lifespan - although numerically equivalent - are different things, semantically speaking. Hope I'm not confusing you even more ;-)