# Pourquoi demande-t-on «Quelle année?» mais «Quel jour?»

Tags: grammaire

Il me semble que normalement le principe guidant l’utilisation de ***jour*** versus ***journée*** devrait être le même que pour **an** versus ***année***. Cependant on m'a dit cette après-midi qu'on demande *« Quelle année ? »* mais *« Quel jour ? »*

Y a-t-il une règle ici ?

Comment: Peux-tu reformuler ta question ? Elle est vraiment très peu claire.

Comment: La finale en -ée, commune à *journée* et *année*, semble être ce qui accroche ici. On pourrait être tenté de dire qu’un an est à une année ce qu’un jour est à une journée. Et pourtant, bien qu’il y ait sans doute quelque chose de ce genre, étonnamment les notions ne sont pas échangeables l’une pour l’autre. On dira ainsi «Quel jour sommes-nous?» (réponse: mardi) ...mais... «**En** quelle ann**ée** sommes-nous?»  *(réponse: **En** 2019)*. Je ne saurais pour l’instant indiquer pourquoi...

Comment: Un sujet qui revient souvent: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/why-is-it-millions-dann%C3%A9es-and-not-millions-dans/16846 https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23255/lan-dernier-or-lann%C3%A9e-derni%C3%A8re/29813 https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27295/what-is-the-difference-between-jour-and-journ%C3%A9e/28195 https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16725/%C3%89tymologiquement-do%C3%B9-vient-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-an-et-ann%C3%A9e-jour-e

Answer (score 1):

Ce que je dis ici est probablement incomplet et pourra potentiellement être amélioré si j'oublie des choses.

1. Un an

On utilise généralement le masculin *un an* dans les cas où l'on cherche à exprimer une unité de temps (j'ai voyagé pendant un an / J'ai mis deux ans à réaliser ce projet / C'est arrivé il y a 3 ans).

2. Une année

On préfère *une année* pour parler de quelque chose en cours, ou un repère dans le temps, ou un an spécifique dans son intégralité (En quelle année la France a-t-elle gagnée la coupe du monde ? / Tu es née en quelle année ? / Ça m'a pris toute l'année / On verra l'année prochaine)

Dans les autres cas, on pourra généralement utiliser indifféremment l'un ou l'autre.

3. Un jour

De même, on utilise généralement le masculin *un jour* dans les cas où l'on cherche à exprimer une unité de temps (j'ai voyagé pendant un jour / J'ai mis deux jours à réaliser ce projet / C'est arrivé il y a 3 jours).

4. Une journée

On préfère *une journée* pour parler de quelque chose en cours, d'un jour spécifique dans son intégralité (J'ai passé une journée épuisante ! / Tu penses y passer la journée ? / Ça m'a pris toute la journée)

Dans les autres cas, on pourra généralement utiliser indifféremment l'un ou l'autre.